# How to get context of PopupWindow?

Tags: android, popupwindow, android-context

I have a progress bar which I want to display inside my `PopupWindow` , but currently it gets displayed out of the window. I think it might be related to Context . How can I do so ? Here is my sample code :

```
protected void onPreExecute(){
      super.onPreExecute();
      progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
      progressdialog.setMessage("Downloading Image");
      progressdialog.show(); 
    }
```

Comment: have used one new activity is act as a popupwindow?

Comment: no the popupwindow is not an activity in my case. Using view and layout inflator in mainactivity to use it.

Comment: Try this: ProgressDialog dialog ;
      protected void onPreExecute() {
   
   dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
     "Downloading Image", true);   
  }

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using a custom view (using layout inflator) You can extend `PopupWindow` and then use `getContentView().getContext()` whenever you need its context

Answer (score 0):

PopupWindow or dialog in your case does not have any context of its own. It takes context of the activity on which its being shown. Same thing for progress dialog. So in your case you can use an activity as an PopupWindow and pass its context into progress dialog

**Edit:**
Add this in manifest to your activity and your activity will work as dialog

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Comment: So I shall create a new activity and use popup window in it? Right now i am using view and layout inflator to set popup in MainActivity. How will I do it according to your method ? Any sample code would be great.

Comment: accordingly you can create activity and give its theam as Theme.Dialog in manifest. Now your activity will work as dialog activity. and you can show progress dialog in it. Check my edited answer